# Heap sort - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a heap sort class and I get this error

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

This is my code

```
package heap_sort;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={16,4,10,14,7,9,3,2,8,1};
        heapsort(a);

    }
public static void heapsort(int a[])
{
    build_max_heap(a);
    for(int i = a.length ;i<=2 ;i--)
    {
        a[1]=a[i];
        max_heapify(a,1,i-1);
    }

}
public static void build_max_heap(int a[])
{
    int n=a.length;
    for (int i =n/2 ;i>=1 ;i--)
    {
        max_heapify(a,i,n);
    }
}
public static void max_heapify(int a[],int i , int n)
{
    int L=i*2;
    int R=(i*2)+1;
    int Largest=i;
    if (L<=n && a[L] > a[i])

    Largest=L;


    if (R>=n && a[R]>a[Largest])
    {
        Largest=R;
    }
    if (Largest != i)
        Changing(a,i,Largest);
    max_heapify(a,Largest,n);
}
public static void Changing (int a[],int i,int LL)
{
    int T=a[i];
    a[i]=a[LL];
    a[LL]=T;
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is my problem and what should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code is that it assumes that the initial index in an array is `1`, and the last index is `a.length`, *inclusive*. For example:

```
for(int i = a.length ; i <= 2 ; i--)
```

This is incorrect. Java array indexes start at zero, and go to `a.length`, *exclusive*. This line of code should look like this:

```
for(int i = a.length-1 ; i >= 1 ; i--)
// The condition is inverted, too: i <= 2 should be i >= 1
```

The other place in code where you made the same assumption need to be fixed as follows:

```
for (int i = n/2 ; i>=1 ; i--)
// should be i >= 0
```

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks, I missed this inversion!

Comment: @luk2302 which condition do you mean

Comment: @luk2302 i still get the same error after fix this 2 conditions